# Assistance with excel formula to match and return value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out a formula to return whether or not a ClassID is eligible for a program or not.

Matching the ClassID on sheet 2 with sheet 1, and returning the head of the column from sheet 1 if there is a yes anywhere in the row of that ClassID. Or a No if there is not.

The caveat is there are multiple instances of the ClassID in sequential rows on sheet 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A:G)/(INDEX(A:G,MATCH(J2,A:A,0),0)="Yes"),1)),"No")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you see the last line?  It reads to me like there may be multiple rows with the same `ClassID`.  If so this will only look at the first match, which may or may not be fine.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I saw. But it was written that several instances are in Sheet2, i.e.  where the result is displayed. Let the OP himself define how he needs it.

Comment: Ah, you may be right.  I may have misinterpreted.

Comment: Yup, this worked a charm, thank you very much.